# how to associate child table values with parent table row and inserts child tables values corresponds to parent table row in php

Tags: php, html

I have 2 nested tables. Parent table row contains child table. Both tables can add rows if needed by add button. parent table values insert in a product_size table in database and child table values inserts in a product_color table. Parent table contains sizes and child table contains color and quantity of items of that size. I want to insert child table values(color & quantity) across parent table row. Means parent first row child table values should insert across parent first row only and the child table values that is in the second row of parent table should insert across parent second row. Currently, my code takes all Child table values from all rows of the parent table and inserts in the database across the first row and then takes all Child table values from all rows of parent table again and inserts in the database across the second row of the parent table. Please Check my code and help me point out where is the problem in my code.
/*PHP CODE*/

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['size']); $i++){

        $size = $_POST['size'][$i];          

        $qry1="INSERT INTO product_size (product_size) VALUES ('$size')";

        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$qry1);
        $product_size_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);                    

        for ($j=0; $j<count($_POST['color']); $j++){

            $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'][$j];

            $color = $_POST['color'][$j];

            $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES ('$product_size_id', '$color', '$quantity')";

            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$qry2); 
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
            }
            else      
            {
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pedram shabani can you help?

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my local server.work's fine

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"login"); 
  // $size1 = array("50", "60", "70");
  // $color1 =array("red", "blue", "green");
  // $quantity1 = array("10", "20", "30");
    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['size']); $i++){

        $size = $size1[$i];   

        $qry1="INSERT INTO product_size (product_size) VALUES ('$size')";
        $result1=mysqli_query($con,$qry1);
        var_dump($result1);
        echo "<br>";

        $product_size_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);                    

        for ($j=0; $j<count($size); $j++){

            $quantity = $_POST['dress_quantity'][$i];

            $color = $_POST['color'][$i];

            $qry2="INSERT INTO product_color (product_size_id, product_color, product_quantity) VALUES ('$product_size_id', '$color', '$quantity')";

            $result2=mysqli_query($con,$qry2); 
            if($result2)
            {
                echo '<script>alert("Record Added Successfully!")</script>';
             //   echo '<script>window.location="try.php"</script>';
            }
            else      
            {
                die("Error While Adding Stock! Please Try Again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks but its for static values not for user input colors and quantity

Comment: Please check the link for detailed working of my website https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149794/inserting-child-table-multiple-rows-across-parent-table-single-row-in-php

Comment: I updated the answer.I have not got your form.For this is use  static values

Comment: Thanks let me check, please also visit link i shared in above comment

Comment: i didn't find from where you change? it looks the same :)

Comment: this line for ($j=0; $j<count(**$_POST['color']**); $j++)  to be for ($j=0; $j<count(**$size**); $j++)